# How to efficently use Drupal as a laboratory notebook and information management system?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, files

I am a chemo-informatics researcher looking to find user experiences and feedback on methods to keep laboratory notebooks on a computer and/or online using Drupal ( e.g. plugins to use, taxonomies).

Comment: Do you want something similar to Google Notes?

Comment: some links : http://linnovate.github.com/openidealapp/ , http://www.scivee.tv/node/21244

Comment: There's no reason to use a CMS as a notebook. Evernote. Microsoft OneNote. Google Docs. There are so many good options built for this task already.

Comment: Actually there are. A CMS can be deployed on web and scale up to your needs. Plus you own the data (vs Google).

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to organize your information?  I would use a content type such as 'notebook_entry' with a taxonomy 'subjects' and/or 'projects' that allows free tagging of terms.

notebook_entry should use the body field for the bulk of your content.  You can add additional text/image/file fields for storing related information that can be displayed with the content.

I recommend using views to display your notebook entries.  You can create an argument in your page view with the taxonomy term or terms you've defined for the notebook_entry content type.  This will make the page only display entries related to that term.  You'll have to create a menu block filtered by the taxonomy to access your content.  It will list each of the taxonomy terms as links to your page view that displays your notebook_entries.  Create a list of terms and use the global text field to make a link to the path of your page view including the arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arosboro. I would also want to create a system that is working like Evernote, being able to sync two drupal installations between my local computer and my online hosting. Do you have heard of a plugin to do that ?

Comment: Why would you want a local installation in the first place? The point of having a web-based solution is not having to install something locally. In case of Evernote, what you have locally is a standalone application, which is something completely different to provide better Usability/Offline capabilities. Synchronizing data like this between multiple installlations (I assume others would then also have local installations, not just you) is quite a complex problem space (Dealing with multiple edits, conflicts, etc.)

Comment: If you want to work locally, consider writing notes as emails with an offline email app, then sending them to a predefined email address when you have Internet access. You can use the Mailhandler module to poll that email box, pick up the notes, map your email contents to desired fields, and create the Drupal nodes.

Comment: @Roland i totally understand your need :) try http://drupal.org/project/deploy